# How do I run a function that I have a pointer to in C++?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I have a pointer to a function called `foo`.  How do I now run the function that this is pointing to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you function has the following signature:

```
void foo(int x);
```

And you have defined the following pointer:

```
void (*ptr)(int) = foo;
```

You can execute foo, through "ptr", like this:

```
ptr(12); //actually calls foo(12);
```

Comment: by the 'declaration-follows-use' rule you can also call it like `(*ptr)(12)`. Function pointers are special in that dereferencing the pointer isn't necessary to access the pointed-to value. And functions are special in that they can be dereferenced and yield the same value: `(*****ptr)(12)`.

Answer (score 4):

The same way you'd run any other function:

```
foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your function pointer is `fp`.

```
void (*fp)(int);
```

You have two ways to call the function from the function pointer:

```
fp(3);
```

or

```
(*fp)(3);
```

The two ways are equivalent but both have their advantages. In the second form it makes explicit to the reader there is no function called  `fp` in the program but that `fp` is a function pointer.